# Greek characters from a webpage

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

I am having problems with Greek characters. I navigate to a webpage that has a textbox & Go button and I programmatically enter a number in the text box and programmatically click "go" button. Then I get the HTML from the webpage. These have some Greek characters. This is the code I have written.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mainURL);
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
request.Timeout = 100000;
request.ContentType = "charset=iso-8859-7;windows-1253;charset=iso-8859-8;windows-1254;";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
try
{
    b.Navigate(mainURL);
    while (b.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
         Application.DoEvents();
     }
string searchNum="10002";
HtmlElement userName = b.Document.GetElementById("ctl00$cphMyMasterCentral$ucSearch$txtNumber");
userName.SetAttribute("value", searchNum);
userName.RemoveFocus();
b.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphMyMasterCentral_ucSearch_lbtnSearch").InvokeMember("click");
string url = "https://www.example.com";
html = wc.DownloadString(url);
html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
```

On the webpage, when I do not do it programmatically this is the output.

```
Name                        Reg. Number Type            NameStatus  OrgStatus
ΑΔΑΜΟΣ ΓΑΒΡΙΗΛΙΔΗΣ & ΣΙΑ    Σ   10002   Partnership     Current Name    Active
```

But when I do it programmatically i get this

```
Name                        Reg. Number Type            NameStatus  OrgStatus
αδα??Σ Γα?????? δ?Σ & Σ?α   Σ   10002   Partnership     Current Name    Active
```

How can I store it as it is shown on the original webpage (eg.ΑΔΑΜΟΣ ΓΑΒΡΙΗΛΙΔΗΣ & ΣΙΑ)?

Comment: Have you tried Encoding.Unicode?

Comment: Set your page encoding to UTF-8 and try getting data from db using N'FOO'

Comment: @Maysam, I do not know what is N'FOO'. Can you elaborate??

Comment: @Rashmi what's your sql code?

Comment: @Maysam, I just parse the HTML using HTMLAgilitypack to get Name, RegNumber...and using sqlbulkcopy copy to sqlserver table.

Comment: @Rashmi when you retrieve data from sql database are they shown correctly?

Comment: @Maysam, I see them as αδα??Σ Γα?????? δ?Σ & Σ?α and not as ΑΔΑΜΟΣ ΓΑΒΡΙΗΛΙΔΗΣ & ΣΙΑ

Comment: @Maysam, you saved my day. I changed the table definition from Varchar to Nvarchar & voila it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change varchar to nvarchar in database table, and change page encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that is the javascript that is messing your code, and your database and the page itself are set to UTF8 thenm if I remember well you need to use hexadecimal characters for the Greek alphabet
[See this page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/greekletters.htm).

κουράγιο